# How to change background colour of a gridview field based on content (date)?

Tags: gridview, colors, field

Having hunted high and low I can't find anything that really works. All I want to do it to display a date field with a Backcolor based on the date (a membership table showing this has expired). It's a relatively simple asp.net website written in C++ (I inherited the job of supporting this two years ago!)

```
<asp:GridView ID="MembershipGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                CellPadding="2" CssClass="ExistingUsersTable" Width="100%" 
                DataKeyNames="Mem_Number" AllowPaging="True" 
                OnPageIndexChanging="AustinMembershipGrid_PageIndexChanging" 
                AllowSorting="True" >
                <FooterStyle BackColor="Teal" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Mem_NumberPrefix" HeaderText="Prefix" HeaderStyle-BackColor="PowderBlue" HeaderStyle-Font-Italic="true" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-Width="15px"/>                    
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Mem_Number" HeaderText="Member Number" HeaderStyle-BackColor="PowderBlue" HeaderStyle-Font-Italic="true" ItemStyle-Width="40px" ItemStyle-BackColor="PaleGreen"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Mem_Firstnames" HeaderStyle-BackColor="PowderBlue" HeaderText="Firstnames" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Mem_Lastname" HeaderStyle-BackColor="PowderBlue" HeaderText="Surname" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Mem_ExpiryDate" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HeaderStyle-BackColor="PowderBlue" 
                        HeaderText="Membership Expiry Date" ItemStyle-Width="11" />
                    <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Mem_Deactive" HeaderStyle-BackColor="PowderBlue" HeaderText="Deactive" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="10"/>
                </Columns>
                <PagerStyle ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" BorderColor="#F7F7DE" 
                    CssClass="PagerStyles" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#F6F5F2" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

So if Mem_Expiry date is before today, I want to show it with a red background, and if equal or after, with a pale green background. Most of what I have found on here seem to be for C# code.

Comment: OK .. solved .. I based it on a test on the content of Cells[4], converting it to a DateTime and then comparing to Today()

Answer (score 0):

In the Gridview segment I added onrowdatabound="gridView1_DataBinding2"

Then in the aspx.cs file:

```
    protected void gridView1_DataBinding2(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)

        {
            DateTime expiryDate = Convert.ToDateTime(e.Row.Cells[4].Text);
            if (expiryDate < DateTime.Today)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkRed;
                e.Row.Cells[4].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.PaleGreen;
            }
        }
    }
```

So when expired the date is white on dark-red and if still had time to go, it's on a palegreen background. Just took a bit of experimenting with the code I found ..